# can my low spec laptop run visual studio 2017

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

I have a laptop with Intel core 2 duo t 5870 processor, 2.5 GB ram. can i run VS 2017 properly. Currently i'm using VS 2015 which run smoothly most of the time.

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your laptop should be able to run Visual Studio 2017, if it runs 2015 smoothly.

Your device has minimum system requirements as well -

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs

Comment: minimum requirements are sometimes tricky, you can run a software with minimum requirements but it's very slow. will this be so?

Comment: Yes! With this specification chances are more that it will be slow. Specially when you use other applications simultaneously. I would recommend update only if you want to use following additional features https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Connect/2016/159